# Is it possible to listen for datastore write event in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm writing an app in Python + GAE, and I was wondering if it would be possible to attach an event listener to whenever I write a specific type of object to the NDB datastore. Currently I am just calling the function whenever I perform updates, but it would be nicer and safer if this just happened on all such write events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at pre and post hooks in ndb.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model__pre_allocate_ids_hook

and the doc on model hooks https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#hooks

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for.